# RStudio: Converting number in the correct form

Tags: r

I'm currently on a table in RStudio like the one below and the column 'system_version' is a type of character, however, some of them are displayed as '8.0.0' which is what I want, while some of them are displayed as integer like '9'. I wonder how should I fix this?

```
------------------------------
|  platform | system_version | 
------------------------------
|      PC     |     8.0.0    | 
------------------------------
|      PC     |       9      | 
------------------------------
|      PC     |     7.0.0    | 
------------------------------
|      PC     |       6      | 
------------------------------
|      PC     |       1      | 
------------------------------
```

```
Desired table:
------------------------------
|  platform | system_version | 
------------------------------
|      PC     |     8.0.0    | 
------------------------------
|      PC     |     9.0.0    | 
------------------------------
|      PC     |     7.0.0    | 
------------------------------
|      PC     |     6.0.0    | 
------------------------------
|      PC     |     1.0.0    | 
------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sub` to replace the elements that have just digits from the start (`^`) to end (`$`) of the string by capturing those elements and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured grouped while inserting the `.0.0`

```
df1$system_version <- sub("^(\\d+)$", "\\1.0.0", df1$system_version)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(platform = c("PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC"), system_version = c("8.0.0", 
"9", "7.0.0", "6", "1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```